# pdo replacing + with space

Tags: php, pdo, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and am trying to insert an email with a `+` sign into a string field in the database.

Unfortunately the `+` is getting decoded to a space in the database.  I traced the code and identified it to be pdo that is changing the value to a space.

The code looks like:

```
$bindings = $me->prepareBindings($bindings);
return $me->getPdo()->prepare($query)->execute($bindings);
```

<strike>If I print the `$bindings` array between the two statements the email is: `email => email+test@email.com`.  However when I check the db it says: `email test@email.com`.</strike>

My broad question is how can I avoid this with Laravel?  Or more specifically how can I avoid it using pdo?

Comment: You've got 3 function calls in that last line; have you tried breaking them up to see which function does the escaping?

Comment: @miken32 Yes, the `execute` is the only statement that knows about the `bindings`.  It is in the execute which binds the values to the placeholders in the query.

Comment: Where does the email address come from? If it's a query param (`$_GET`), it should be URL encoded, ie `http://example.com/?email=email%2Btest@email.com`

Comment: Where is that code you traced located? Please post the code you're using to save the data to the database. I've just tried to replicate your issue by saving that email address using both Laravel's Query Builder, as well as from an Eloquent model, both worked without problems. What client are you using to view the saved data?

Comment: :( I just found the issue isn't in the builder or PDO.  I am seeing that the error is happening in the front end.  @Bogdan I tested it from the front end and it wasn't entering the database correctly, so I sidestepped the front end and started tracing the request using dd().  As a result the query never made it to the db.  Had I let it go the db I would have seen it was the front end that filtered it.  I am sending it as json via a put or a post request.

Comment: Please post the code that is relevant to the question. If the problem is with the code we need to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong.  PDO isn't sanitizing it.  The front end was sanitizing it so it has nothing to do with Laravel or PDO.  It is jquery, which means I just wasted an hour because I didn't take that 1 additional step when debugging.  Lesson learned.

In the front end I am using this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/customers/"+$("#Id").val(),
      data:data,
      type: "PUT",
      success: function(html) {
          ...
      },
      error: function(response){
          ...
      }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping the + sign by adding a backslash in front of it.

```
email\+test@email.com
```